# Memory leak when adding subview

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

When adding a subview, the view controller seems to leak.

Why does the following print 'What'

```
import UIKit

final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var mySwitch: UISwitch = {
        let mySwitch = UISwitch()
        mySwitch.tintColor = .blue
        return mySwitch
    }()

    func setup() {
        view.addSubview(mySwitch)
    }

    @objc func switchChangedState() {

    }

    deinit {
        print("what")
    }
}

var controller: ViewController? = ViewController()
controller = nil
```

But the following does not

```
var controller: ViewController? = ViewController()
controller?.setup()
controller = nil
```

**Edit**: adding GIF

[image]

Xcode Version 9.4.1 (9F2000)

Comment: Why is it final ?

Comment: Hi @TomSchulz. I write final out of habit. In this particular example it's not needed. That being said, I would recommend adding final anyway, as a habit, until you are ready to support subclassing.

Comment: Disagree. It's not like you can ship a header file and a library anyway. If somebody wants things to not be final they just edit your code. 'Support subclassing'; the language supports subclassing.

Comment: @TomSchulz i don't understand what what you mean by 'ship a header file and a library' or 'just edit your code'.

Comment: @TomShulz I recommend adding final if you are not ready to support subclassing. Of course, you and others can change that in the future that's the idea. Change it when you are ready to subclass. Besides, adding final is performance improvement. https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=27

Comment: I mean that whoever will be working with your code with not be working with C dot h fle and a compile library (ie lib.a ) and if they want to subclass, all the other programmer needs do is edit out your 'final' keyword and he is off to the races. OTOH, I did not know final was faster, although I have to wonder just how much is saved.

Comment: If someone attempts to subclass a class that is final, when they shouldn't, then the compiler will prevent a successful build. This is helpful. If another developer wants to subclass a class that is declared as final then presumably that other developer has reviewed the class thoroughly and has deemed it suitable for subclassing. Or has made the necessary changes to the class so that final can be safely removed. If you don't trust this other developer, then you should kick him or her off the team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. There's no retain cycle here.

The problem appears to be something to do with the playground. It could be a bug, or the playground may be retaining your view controller for some reason.

If you execute your code in an actual Xcode project (either in the iOS simulator or on a device), the initializer is executed in both cases:

[image: deinit executes in both cases]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is good. `controller?.setup()` will not cause a leak. Please make sure the code in test case 2 is really called or not. (No calling no "what" printed)

Comment: I second this - there's no retain cycle here. When I build and run your code, the deinitializer is called in both cases.

Comment: Hi @PeteMorris. I agree, the code definitely suggests that there is no retain cycle here but the behaviour I'm seeing suggests otherwise. Have added a gif to demonstrate.

Comment: Hi @YunCHEN have added gif to post.

Comment: @Jonesy That's something to do with the playground, there's nothing wrong with your code at all. Perhaps its a bug, or perhaps the playground retains your controller for some reason. If you go and run the exact same code in an actual Xcode project, the deinitializer will definitely be run in both cases: https://imgur.com/a/QkLn6Q3

Comment: Thanks @PeteMorris will accept if you make it an offical answer

Comment: @Jonesy, as Pete Morris said, PlayGround may have some bugs to hold your controller. To prove that, add `controller = ViewController()` twice at the end (after `controller = nil`), you will get the "what" printed, means the former controller is really released. So it's not a retain cycle.